After starting Kafka-connect, the warn message keeps getting and it won't be turned off
I'm running bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties
But this message will always appear
                          WARN [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] 25 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [__consumer_offsets-9, __consumer_offsets-39, __consumer_offsets-11, __consumer_offsets-31, __consumer_offsets-13, __consumer_offsets-43, __consumer_offsets-29, __consumer_offsets-1, __consumer_offsets-41, __consumer_offsets-27] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1056)
[2024-05-08 17:00:18,892] WARN [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] 25 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [__consumer_offsets-9, __consumer_offsets-39, __consumer_offsets-11, __consumer_offsets-31, __consumer_offsets-13, __consumer_offsets-43, __consumer_offsets-29, __consumer_offsets-1, __consumer_offsets-41, __consumer_offsets-27] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1056)
[2024-05-08 17:00:18,994] WARN [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] 25 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [__consumer_offsets-9, __consumer_offsets-39, __consumer_offsets-11, __consumer_offsets-31, __consumer_offsets-13, __consumer_offsets-43, __consumer_offsets-29, __consumer_offsets-1, __consumer_offsets-41, __consumer_offsets-27] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1056)
[2024-05-08 17:00:19,096] WARN [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] 25 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [__consumer_offsets-9, __consumer_offsets-39, __consumer_offsets-11, __consumer_offsets-31, __consumer_offsets-13, __consumer_offsets-43, __consumer_offsets-29, __consumer_offsets-1, __consumer_offsets-41, __consumer_offsets-27] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1056)
[2024-05-08 17:00:19,197] WARN [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] 25 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [__consumer_offsets-9, __consumer_offsets-39, __consumer_offsets-11, __consumer_offsets-31, __consumer_offsets-13, __consumer_offsets-43, __consumer_offsets-29, __consumer_offsets-1, __consumer_offsets-41, __consumer_offsets-27] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1056)

And I can't turn it off even if I use CTRL+C
# A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster.
bootstrap.servers=192.168.245.128:9092,192.168.245.129:9092,192.168.245.130:9092

# unique name for the cluster, used in forming the Connect cluster group. Note that this must not conflict with consumer group IDs
group.id=connect-cluster

key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
#offset.storage.partitions=25

config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1

status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
#status.storage.partitions=5

# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

# These are provided to inform the user about the presence of the REST host and port configs 
# Hostname & Port for the REST API to listen on. If this is set, it will bind to the interface used to listen to requests.
#rest.host.name=
rest.port=8085

# The Hostname & Port that will be given out to other workers to connect to i.e. URLs that are routable from other servers.
#rest.advertised.host.name=
#rest.advertised.port=

# Examples: 
# plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,
plugin.path=/home/hadoop/kafka_2.11-2.4.0/plugins

Is there a problem with the connect-distributed.properties I configured.That's how all three of my machines are configured

The consumer offsets topic is configured by your kafka broker properties, not kafka connect

3Q，I use nohup bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties > /dev/null 2>&1& and it's ok

That's just hiding all log output. It's not a safe operation, and doesn't mean there isn't a configuration issue in the broker properties

Can you look at connect-distributed.properties for me? This has bothered me for a long time

I wouldn't use a replication factor of 1 for the topics, but looks fine. As mentioned, the consumer offsets topic mentioned on your log output is not configured by that file. It's configured by server.properties
